# Использование FluentValidation в патерне "Repository"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, repository

Как использовать FluentValidation в патерне репозиторий, когда необходимо проверить уникальность, например, логина (проверяется в БД)?

Пояснение:

Решение состоит из 4 проектов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура проекта RTLservise.Model:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс `UserValidator`:

```
  public class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<User>
{      
    public UserValidator()
    {          
        RuleFor(x => x.Login)
            .Must(CheckUserName)
            .WithMessage("Login некорректный.");
            .Must(IsLoginUnique)
            .WithMessage("Пользователь с таким логином уже зарегистрирован.");

    }

    private bool CheckUserName(string login)
    {
        if (login == null)
            return false;
        string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,49}$";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

        return regex.IsMatch(login);
    }
}
```

Выполнить `CheckUserName` не составило труда.
**НО:**
Проверить пользователя на уникальность (выполнить функцию `uf_Bit_exists_login` ), например так:

```
  public bool IsLoginUnique(string login)
    {
        if (login == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "uf_Bit_exists_login";
                var returnValue = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
                returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                return (bool)returnValue.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

И вот тут все тесты сразу падают.

Правильно ли размещать проверку, связанную с подключением к БД именно в классе валидатора??

Хотелось конечно что-то, наподибие:

```
IUserRepository _repository = new UserRepository();
```

А затем выполнить проверку:

```
 _repository.IsLoginUnique(string)
```

НО: это невозможно, т.к. возникают циклические ссылки:(
Тогда может перенести логику валидирования в службу? Неясно, при таком подходе проектирования, где вообще выполнять проверку?

Comment: Я считаю, что должна быть условная валидация "если валидация свойств прошла, то уже потом лезть в базу проверять". И на эту тему есть мой issue на гитхабе и ответ вида "такого нет и вносить не планируется". Таким образом переходим к решению "цепочка валидаторов" и набор валидаторов ValidatorsChain, то есть абстракция уровнем выше - если первый валидатор прошел, то можно вызывать второй, который проверит бд. Готового ValidatorsChain в либе вроде нет, у меня руки не дошли, но вы сами можете написать.

Comment: В чём проблема пробросить **IUserRepository repository** через конструктор из DI ?